# Can you force a broadcast for updating widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have almost finished making my first app, a battery widget and it all works fairly well. The only thing that is bothering me is that i have a broadcast reciver for when the battery level changes it updates the widget, but when i first add the widget to the home screen it then waits for the battery level / state to change. (plugging or uplugging the device updates it too). Changing the intent filter to other means of sending a boradcast doesn't work as it doesn't carry the battery level. I was wondering if there is a way for force a broadcast with the battery level information?

Thanks, Phil.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling

```
AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(ComponentName, RemoteViews);
```

in your onUpdate() method of your widget provider. When the widget is created it should automatically run onUpdate()